# Where can I find old c++ header files

Tags: c++, header

I'm trying to implement A* algorithms.
Paht of standard A* algorism is too robotic, so I'm trying to postprocess using this way on this article.
(http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131505/toward_more_realistic_pathfinding.php?page=2)

This article provide source codes, but it too outdated.
Especially, where can I find

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include "general.h"
#include "linklist.h"
#include "path.h"
```

header files?
Source code in this article is written 2000 and it's hard to use it for me.

Please let me know how to use upper source code.

Comment: Windowsx.h should just be there. afxwin.h is for [MFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library). I'm not sure where you get that these days outside of a paid edition for Visual Studio. You'll have to google that one. The rest of them, if they are not included in the source post, you're probably in for a rough go. LinkedList you can probably replace with std::list, though.

Comment: Thanks to user4581301
I googled "pathfinding smoothing" and second top article was this which was posted on gamasutra written near 2000. And source code is attached in the last page of the article. I really need to postprocess a* algorithm so I should analysis method.

Comment: You don't need windows header for A*. Maybe they added some fancy windows to show their results.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not absence of "old c++ header files". Please read carefully readme.txt and article. This source code (path.h + path.cpp) is not complete source code for creating Pathing.exe. It is only part of full source code. The goal - the demonstration of technics, which describing in article.
You must create yourself program, which can use this part of code.